# Angular is not showing my records

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new for Angular and trying to do one exercise and result is not showing on browser.

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('bus', []);

  app.controller('BusContorller', function() {
    this.busbarnd = basname;
  });

  var basname = {
    name: 'tata',
    yearprod: 2000,
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- container -->
<div class="container" ng-app="bus">
  <!-- row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
      <!-- Call controller -->
      <div ng-controller="BusContorller as bus">
        <p>Bus name : {{bus.busbarnd.name}}</p>
      </div>
      <!--// Call controller -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- // row end -->
</div>
<!-- // container -->
```

Kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong. I'm thinking I'm making mistake in calling controller.

Comment: You need to look in your console and see what error you are getting. After you do that, post the error here.

Comment: Your code is working, I just added the Angular library

Comment: Your code is working, but you should not use data binding this way. You should make use of the `$scope` service

Comment: Thanks Charleshaa for guiding me to use $scope service

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="bus">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('bus',[]);

        app.controller('BusContorller', function($scope){
            $scope.busbarnd = $scope.basname;

        $scope.basname = {
            name: 'tata',
            yearprod: 2000,
        }
        });



  </script>

  <body ng-controller="BusContorller">
    <div ng-controller="BusContorller as bus">
        <p>Bus name : {{busbarnd.name}}</p>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```